# Using TestComplete's UIAObject with Microsoft UI Automation Control Patterns

Tags: ui-automation, testcomplete, uia

In TestComplete, the UIAObject "ControlPatterns" property lists the Microsoft UIA Control Patterns for an object.

General Question : 
How do you invoke these control patterns against the UIAObject?

Specific Question: 
How do you get the column header for a DataGridCell given you have the UIAObject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, TestComplete supports patterns for UI Automation objects. The patterns' members are available as the corresponding object's members in TestComplete. You do not need to cast an object to a pattern or invoke a pattern in any other special ways.

As for your specific question, you can get the index of the column via the **column** property and then find the corresponding column by this index.

```
var dataCellObj = dataGridObj.UIAObject("RowsPresenter").UIAObject("Example_Nutrition_2").UIAObject("DataGridCell");
var colIndex = dataCellObj.column;
var column = dataGridObj.UIAObject("ColumnHeadersPresenter").Child(colIndex);
Log.Message(column.NativeUIAObject.Name);
```